# Calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) returns 31 allways

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

i have this code to calculate last day of the previous month of the month selected by the user. Variable monthNumber gives me the month selected my the user:

```
        lastDayOfPreviousMonth.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        lastDayOfPreviousMonth.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber-1);
        lastDayOfPreviousMonth.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH , lastDayOfPreviousMonth.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

the problem is that `lastDayOfPreviousMonth.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));` gives me allways 31. ¿Why?

thanks

Comment: use `lastDayOfPreviousMonth.getMaximum` instead of `getActualMaxium`. I feel once you see this youll understand the diff :-/

Comment: @Panther: `getMaximum` says `for any possible time value`. I don't think this would work.

Comment: Can you give actual values you tested for `year` and `monthNumber`?

Comment: year is the year, and monthnumber has a value from 0 to 11

Answer (score 0):

This is not the appropriate way to obtain the maximum number of days in the previous month. Try the following:

```
calendarPreviousMonth.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have verified your program and just add the necessary declarations and format output:

```
GregorianCalendar lastDayOfPreviousMonth = new GregorianCalendar(2012, 2, 1);
int month = 5; // May (here 1-based month)

lastDayOfPreviousMonth.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
// 2 for one-based month-input and previous month
lastDayOfPreviousMonth.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 2);
lastDayOfPreviousMonth.set(
    Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
    lastDayOfPreviousMonth.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
);

System.out.println(lastDayOfPreviousMonth.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
// output: 30

System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(lastDayOfPreviousMonth.getTime()));
// output: 30.04.2015
```

It works for me. Maybe you should check your initialization and/or use this example code on Dalvik VM.